# how using GPU from c# code to compress bitmap

Tags: c#, gpuimage, gpu

I want to compress bitmap that i getting from some source ( compress bitmap to image in jpeg or png format or compress group of images to clip )

I want to try to do it by using the GPU to have better performance.

I know that Intel and Nvidia have some dll that expose those abilities.

How to do it ?
Does using those library will have better performance than using simple C# GDI+ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "compress bitmap" do you mean put it inside a zip file or similar or do you mean converting it from bitmap format to a compressed format like jpeg or png?

Comment: Thanks - embedded fix